# Is there a way I can remove DB migration from an ASP.NET Core project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Is there a way I can remove migration that already added to the database? I am working on an ASP.NET CORE Project and I am using VS 3.1

Comment: Migrations are just source code. DB versioning engine tracks applied migrations in some table in a database instance. If you can drop all affected DBs and migrate them from scratch - then remove the migration from your source code and do it. Otherwise, if any affected DBs are already shared with other developers or running in production, removing a migration is strongly discouraged, and you should provide a compensating migration instead. That's because otherwise different members of your team will know different truth about the DB which will lead to communication and maintanance issues.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove Migration**

Sometimes you add a migration and realize you need to make additional changes to your EF Core model before applying it. To remove the last migration, you can use the following command.

```
PM> Remove-Migration
```

---

**Revert Migration**

If you already applied several migrations to the database but need to revert it, you can use the Update-Database command but also specify the name of the migration you want to roll back to.

```
PM> Update-Database LastGoodMigration
```

For better understanding of EF Core Migrations Tools, check

[EF Core Docs](https://entityframeworkcore.com/migrations)

and

[EF Core Docs from Microsoft docs website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)